# How to check whether an array contains an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to restrict keys that can be pressed.

```
$('.txtComments').keydown(function (event) {
  var keys = new Array();
  keys[0] = "8";
  keys[1] = "46";
  keys[2] = "37"
  keys[3] = "39"

  if(!(....)) //Check whether the keyCode is either of 8, 46, 37, or 39. 
  {
     event.preventDefault();  
  }
});
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: `var keys = [8,46,37,39];`, then you can use `$.inArray` and `event.which`

Comment: Try using [`$.inArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)

Comment: Be nice. Stop voting down. Thanks.

Comment: Use `let excludeCode = [20, 16, 17, 18, 32]`
`if ( excludeCode.includes(event.which) ) {}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are *so* many ways to implement this:

Just hard code it:

```
var keyCode = event.which;

if (keyCode != 8 && keyCode != 46 ...)
```

or check an array:

```
var keys = [8, 46, ...];
if (keys.indexOf(keyCode) < 0)
```

or the jQuery equivalent:

```
if ($.inArray(keyCode, keys) < 0)
```

or check an object:

```
var keys = { 8: 1, 46: 1, ... }
if (! (keyCode in keys) )  // or if (!keys[keyCode])
```

or a switch:

```
switch (keyCode) {
    case 8: case 46: ...
        // do nothing
        break;
    default:
        event.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest (and fastest) here would be to use an object as map :

```
   var keys = {};
   keys[8] = true;
   ...

   if (!keys[event.which]) {
     ...
```

Note that I suggest to use [event.which](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) instead of the keycode for better compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery provides the utility method [`jQuery.inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) to check if an array contains a value.

Answer (score 0):

`if(!keys.in_array(event.keyCode));`

And change your `keydown` to `keypress`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Benoit Asselin - http://www.ab-d.fr
Array.prototype.in_array = function(p_val) {
    for(var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++) {
        if(this[i] == p_val) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:-

```
   var keys = [];
    keys[8] = keys[4] = keys[37] = keys[39] = true;

if(keys[keyval]){

}
```